# Read File Name containg with fixed character in Node.js

Tags: node.js

[image]

I have a daily task to replace text from  files and then Rename the files.
In this picture there are 3 different .txt files. My first approach will be like :

- read the SEC_20220522.txt  file
- replace some datas like 'abcd' to 'xyz'
- rename file SEC_20220522.txt to SEC.txt

and then same for other files.

How I can read the file SEC_20220522.txt without passing the file name as it is

```
fs.readFile('SEC_20220522.txt', 'utf-8', function(err, data)
```

I mean, can I read this file by its first 3 characters 'SEC' or any other options? because everyday filename will be change. only 'SEC' part will be constant.

> ```
> var fs = require('fs');
>  
> fs.readFile('SEC_20220522.txt', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
>     if (err) throw err;
>  
>     var newValue = data.replaceAll("abcd", "xyz");
>  
>     fs.writeFile('SEC_20220522.txt', newValue, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
>         if (err) throw err;
>         console.log('Data Updated Successfully!');
>     })
>     fs.renameSync('SEC_20220522.txt', 'SEC.txt');
> })
> ```

Comment: You can [read the directory](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/fs.html#fsreaddirpath-options-callback) containing the files and then read each file in that directory.

Comment: Also notet that `renameSync` is executing _before_ `writeFile` completes because it is asynchronous. You probably want to call `renameSync` inside the callback function of `writeFile`.

Comment: I am able to read the directory with containg 3 files. now how I can read the SEC file automatically ?

Comment: the fs module API has his function called: `fs.readdir` ([link](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreaddirpath-options)), so you could do this: `fs.readdir(process.cwd(), async function (err, files){
  if(err){
   return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
  }

`, where files is an iterable with every file inside the folder

Comment: @devperate   reading the directory is working for me.three .txt files are listed. But now how can I read only the SEC file?

Comment: with `fs.readFileSync(file);` where file is an iterable element of the files, so you can restrict if read or not the file by checking his name like this: `if(file.contains('SEC')){}`, besides if you are a little bit familiar with nodejs you can check the code of my sub-adjuster proyect in npm so you could get some code snippets and ideas from there